# google analytics stopped tracking after domain change

Tags: google-analytics

I just want to be sure, we moved old doamin to new top level domain (.eu>.cz), after doing that I changed all names + property- default URL + default view - website URL in the analytics account to new .cz domain and updated the 
ga create in the tracking code to new domain too

```
ga('create', 'UA-.......-..', '.....cz');
```

Now I see the realtime visitors but no audience count..... Is there anything else I can do?
in the tracking code i see status: Receiving Data
so guess I just have to wait longer? /its already over 24 hours since the changes/

Please let me know if anyone has experience about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Processing latency is 24-48 hours. Standard accounts that send more than 200,000 sessions per day to Google Analytics will result in the reports being refreshed only once a day.](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1070983?hl=en)

Just wait.

Comment: yeah it started working for new records, days, but for some reason there still is missing that one day data, and switching to hourly view I see it is missing exactly from hour 0 to hour 24 that day